# spacy Entity Linking at paragraph level

Tags: spacy, spacy-3, entity-linking

Entity linking works well for sentence based one. How to use spacy entity linking for a paragraph level instead of sentence level text? Any guidance on it would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a difficult task. You could probably treat it as either a classification problem with many labels (extreme classification) or a search problem (find the nearest document in your db given the input).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply... Just to be clear, i want to take into account the entire paragraph as a context for entity linking for an entity taking into account many factors. Please guide or share links for the same...